# How to access XHR requests using Chrome DevTools Protocol?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I want to access live XHR request data in Chrome programatically. (I can't just connect to the website using a script, it **must** go through Chrome)

So far, I've found the easiest way to do this is to launch Chrome with `remote-debugging` turned on. And then use `Chrome DevTools` to get the data:

```
import PyChromeDevTools

chrome = PyChromeDevTools.ChromeInterface()
chrome.Network.enable()
chrome.Page.enable()
chrome.Page.navigate(url='http://example.com/')
```

The Chrome DevTools protocol guide is here:
https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/

But I don't know how to actually access the live XHR requests.

Here's the data shown in the Chrome DevTools UI:
[image]

The `connect` requests contain everything I need in the response body. I simply need access to them live (as they continue to stream in).

I just want to access this data using DevTools-protocol so I can further process it.

Any ideas how?

Comment: I guess https://github.com/marty90/PyChromeDevTools#31-receive-events

Comment: You need to connect via WebSocket and wait for messages. I don't know how it's done using the library you are using.